# Composition of ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have three rings $A,B,C$ and ring homomorphisms $f: A \rightarrow B$
and $g: B \rightarrow C$, which are both surjective.
Is it true that $C$ is isomorphic to
$$
A / (\ker(f), \ker(g)) ?
$$
If so how can I show this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not quite true. $\ker(g)$ is not a subset of $A$, so you can't take the quotient. The ring $C$ will be isomorphic to $A/\ker(g\circ f)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it can't be since $\ker(g)$ is an ideal in $B$, but not in $A$.

**Hint:** What is the kernel of $g\circ f$?

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain her reasons?